# Should programming project-related ideas be asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope

I wish to do a certain project and want a few innovative ideas and explore the possibilities on the chosen topic. (Googling about it did not help very much.)

Should I ask regarding it on Stack Overflow, because I noticed on the right-hand side before asking a question that "*We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.*"?

If not, what other place is suitable for such things?

Comment: No, your question would turn out to be _too vague_, _too broad_.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, IRC/Slack/whatever channel, or mailing list. It's a Q&A site. But those are all better places to ask your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow Chat would be okay, so long as the chat room you're in is willing to accept the discussion.

Otherwise, you're left with options that aren't on Stack Overflow; IRC, bulletin boards, or talking with other friends.

There's no answer for how you want to start a project, so with it being an open ended question, it'll get closed outright.